# LWUIT Tabs creation

Tags: java-me, lwuit

i have created LWUIT Tabs and added my LWUIT List to the Tabs and Displayed,but my Problem is,when i add number of List items to the Tab,those list items are displayed ,but when i scroll up my List,my Tab will also gets scrolled,how to fix my tab position? 
Here my Code:

```
tabs=new Tabs(Component.BOTTOM);
        tabs.addTab("TopNews", myNewsList);       
        form1.addComponent(tabs);
        form1.show();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
form1.setScrollable(false);
```

And ideally also:

```
form1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
form1.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, tabs);
```